# External microphone (headset) doesn't work on Macbook Pro 2015 (19.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, macbook, microphone, headset

Just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Macbook Pro 13" from 2015 and it works so great compared to OS X Mojave, but the problem is that it doesn't recognize any other microphone than the Built-in.

I tried both solutions with setting `Duplex` in `pavucontrol` and adding a proper line to alsa-base.conf `options snd-hda-intel model=mbp11`and nothing works.

My audio chip is **Cirrus Logic CS4208**

Any ideas on how to make it works?

Comment: What's interesting, an external microphone is working while connected via Bluetooth.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. The pavucontrol shows the external mic as "unplugged". However, if I launch pavucontrol while recording with an audio recording software, the external microphone works when I choose it in pavucontrol.